# Why in my pnp.ini the memory limit is given like this?

Tags: nginx, server, nginx-config

In my php.ini the memory limit is given like this:

memory_limit => -1 => -1

Why is it doubled? Is this setting working like this at all?

Should not it be in a form:

memory_limit => -1 ?

I am using NGINX server on an Ubuntu machine.